# fast-export git lfs repository

Tags: git, git-lfs

I have a git repository with a great number of .exe files inside.
The .exe files are stored using LFS and now I want to move the repository to a new hub.

Directly fast-exporting the repository only exports the LFS references, not the actual data.

I would like to fast-export the entire repository with the .exe actual content and not references. Is it possible? How?

Thanks.

Comment: @Mike-O you're looking for e.g. `git fast-export --all -- \*.java`. Your question should not have been downvoted or closed, it was just mistagged.